# ambiguity about the relationship between 2 UML entities? Can you tell me what kind of relationship is there?

Tags: uml, entity, staruml

[image]

ambiguity about the relationship between 2 UML entities? Can you tell me what kind of relationship is there?

Answer (score 0):

The black diamond means composite aggregation.

The arrow heads on both side mean that the aggregation is navigable in both direction, i.e. the `RightSpecifications` find easily its `AssignedRights`, and vice-versa, each `AssignedRights` finds easily its `RightSpecification` owner.

Navigation expresses a promise about finding the other side in an efficient way at runtime.  You could as well not show the navigation (i.e. navigability unspecified) by removing the arrowhead, and you'll get an ordinary composite aggregation.

**P.S**:
the arrowhead against the diamond looks weird, and it is therefore seldom used.